# Eloquent get deeper relation where column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get all relations where a column has a specific value.

I have 3 models:

1. Productions
2. ProductionPackages
3. ProductionProducts

The relationships:
1 Production can have multiple ProductionPackages and 1 ProductionPackages can have multiple ProductionProducts.

My goal: I want a list with all ProductionProducts where the supplier_id equals a id.

The problem: The production model has a status and a date. I only need the products for the productions where date < current_date and status = 1.

This is my current code, it returns the productionProducts but it does not check the where on the production itself, so it also returns the productionProducts where the status = 0.

```
public function productEntryInput($supplierId){
        $supplier = Supplier::find($supplierId);
       $productions = ProductionProducts::with(['productionPackage', 'productionPackage.production' =>  function ($query) use ($supplier) {
           $inputDate = Date('Y-m-d');
           $query->where('status', 1)->where('packing_plant_id', Session::get('user_packingPlant'))
               ->whereDate('delivery_date', '<',$inputDate);
       }])
           ->where('supplier_id', $supplier->id)
           ->get();

        dd($productions);

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? The closure in the with is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to use withWhereHas:

```
public function productEntryInput($supplierId){
    $supplier = Supplier::find($supplierId);
    $productions = ProductionProducts::with('productionPackage')
        ->withWhereHas('productionPackage.production', function ($query) use ($supplier) {
            $inputDate = Date('Y-m-d');
           $query->where('status', 1)
               ->where('packing_plant_id', Session::get('user_packingPlant'))
               ->whereDate('delivery_date', '<',$inputDate);
        })->where('supplier_id', $supplier->id)
        ->get();

    dd($productions);

}
```

Let me explain it:

**With() method** will get productionPackage.production that match the   conditions in the closure. The method does nothing with    ProductionProducts

**WithWhereHas() method** will get not only productionPackage.production    that matches the conditions in the closure but also    ProductionProducts

Comment: I added the explanation in my answer. Hope you understand my words